# While refreshing the react js project it gives 404 error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created a project based on React JS and also uploaded the file to the server but when I navigate to another link tab like `https://localhost:3000/about` and refresh the page it gives the 404 error. How I can solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: `localhost/about` doesn't seem like a valid url. there is probably a port like `localhost:3000/about`

Comment: I just give the path like /about

Comment: @nullptr notice the `m` as the last character, and "uploaded the file to the server". this is deployed to a production server

Answer (score 2):

I was getting 404 whenever i was refreshing the page. So what i did is...

If you have build your React JS App using

```
yarn build
OR 
npm run build
```

and is being hosted on an Apache Server. Then you can add htaccess on the root of the application

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

if you are using something other than apache please refer to this link, it might help

https://tecadmin.net/solving-react-404-error/

I hope this might help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be because you're doing client side routing with a library (the most popular one is [`react-router-dom`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom)). This works when you start on the root page, but since you've deployed on a static server if you were to reload on any other path than `/` you'd get a 404. To fix this, you have a couple options:

- Use a [HashRouter](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/routers/hash-router)
- Get a more complex server that returns `index.html` instead of a 404 on any `GET` requests that aren't fulfilled by a file
- Upgrade to a fullstack React-based framework that handles routing, like NextJS, Gatsby, Remix, etc.

Answer (score 0):

this error gets when you build react app and render the file as statice files
you need to create render route return react files like this:

```
//expressjs
    app.get("*",(req,res)=>{
    
    retrun YourReactProjectIndexFile()
    
    })
```

Comment: I have to do this in react js

Comment: you can't, you sending files from the server you need to type func to return react file for  any request